# SQL: call second query if no rows are returned from the first query

Tags: sql, database, join, db2

I'm struggling to combine these two statements I've put together into a single statement.

My first statement is in effect 3 statements in where I only want the first statement that returns a value to be returned, which works a treat.

```
SELECT ReferenceKey, ReferenceValue FROM
(   
    SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 1 as preference 
    FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076  AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
    WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = 'EUR'  
    UNION
    SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 3 as preference 
    FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN  OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076 AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
    WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = ''
    UNION
    SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 3 as preference 
    FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN  OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076 AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
    WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = '' AND a.CURN076 = ''
)BankPayingFrom ORDER BY preference
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

However, if none of these three statements return any information I want to be able fire off the SQL statement below to retrieve all possible records.

```
SELECT BANK11 as ReferenceKey, TRIM(BANK11) ||' - '|| BANM11 as ReferenceValue From OSLTHLF3.CSP11 WHERE CONO11 = '01'
```

How do I join both these statements together so that I need only make one call from my web service to the back end database (AS/400 DB2 database)?

I’d appreciate any assistance.

Many thanks
Christian

Comment: Do you need all those `UNION`s?  Could you use the one statement, with a number of `OR`s as appropriate (and potentially a `CASE`)?

Comment: Really not sure if I do, but I got that to work from searching on google and to be fair when I got it to work, I stopped there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your dataset it's hard to know for sure, but I believe this may be a cleaner alternative.  It *may* perform faster, as well, but I can't guarantee that.

```
WITH  BankPayingFrom (referenceKey, referenceValue) as (
      SELECT a.GBNK076, TRIM(b.BANK11) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 -- typo? 'b.BANK11'?
      FROM THTFU.THAP076P as a
      LEFT JOIN OSLTHLF3.CSP11 as b
                ON b.BANK11 = a.GBNK067
                   AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076
      WHERE a.CONO076 = '01'
            AND ((a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = 'EUR')
                 OR (a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = '')
                 OR (a.PMTH076 = '' AND a.CURN076 = ''))
            -- You may be able to use the following, but only if
            -- a.PMTH076 is set for every set value of a.CURN076
               -- AND (a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' OR a.PMTH067 = '')
               -- AND (a.CURN076 = 'EUR' OR a.CURN076 = '')
      ORDER BY a.PMTH076 DESC, a.CURN076 DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)

SELECT referenceKey, referenceValue 
FROM BankPayingFrom
UNION 
SELECT BANK11 as referenceKey, TRIM(BANK11) ||' - '|| BANM11 as referenceValue
FROM  OSLTHLF3.CSP11
WHERE CONO11 = '01'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                      FROM BankPayingFrom)
```

... Although looking at it further, the only real difference is `a.GBNK076` in the CTE.  Is it that you only want 1 row if a 'matching' row exists in `THAP076P`, otherwise you want all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about AS/400 (iSeries), but here's how I might do it on Linux Unix Windows:

```
WITH BankOrderFromOne(ReferenceKey, ReferenceValue)
AS (
    SELECT ReferenceKey, ReferenceValue FROM
    (   
        SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 1 as preference 
        FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076  AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
        WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = 'EUR'  
        UNION
        SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 3 as preference 
        FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN  OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076 AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
        WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = 'BMG' AND a.CURN076 = ''
        UNION
        SELECT a.GBNK076 AS ReferenceKey, TRIM(a.GBNK076) ||' - '||  b.BANM11 AS ReferenceValue, 3 as preference 
        FROM THTFU.THAP076P AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN  OSLTHLF3.CSP11  AS b ON  b.BANK11 = a.GBNK076 AND b.CONO11 = a.CONO076 
        WHERE a.CONO076 = '01' AND a.PMTH076 = '' AND a.CURN076 = ''
    )BankPayingFrom ORDER BY preference
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)

SELECT ReferenceKey, ReferenceValue FROM BankOrderFromOne

UNION

SELECT BANK11 as ReferenceKey, TRIM(BANK11) ||' - '|| BANM11 as ReferenceValue From OSLTHLF3.CSP11 WHERE CONO11 = '01'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ReferenceKey, ReferenceValue FROM BankOrderFromOne)
```